# AngularJS - Controller value not dispaying

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.0

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TestController as controller">

    {{controller.test}}

    <script src="libraries/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("TestController", function() {
  var test = "Hello World";

//  window.alert(test); THIS ALERT IS WORKING
});
```

In my index, it doesn't display anything. However, alerting the test variable does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` variable is private to your controller. Assign it to the controller instance:

```
this.test = 'Whatever';
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine with the detailed reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `$scope` to bind value in html code.

```
app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Hello World";
});
```

or you can use `this` to create current controller's instance

```
app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
  this.test = "Hello World";
});
```

Comment: In his example he want's to avoid use of `$scope`, that's why uses controller as syntax.

Comment: ahh! yes I didn't notice that, any way thanks @Raulucco :)

Answer (score 2):

Assign value to `$scope`

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
   $scope.test = "Hello World";

 //  window.alert(test); THIS ALERT IS WORKING
});
```

or you can also use the other way

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
   this.test = "Hello World";

 //  window.alert(test); THIS ALERT IS WORKING
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to display a value from controller itself you should assign it to controller using `this` keyword: `this.test = "your value here"`. If you want to use controllers' scope so do `$scope.test = "value here"` and in view use it with `{{test}}`.

When you declaring your variable with `var` keyword it will be `private`, but to use it it view you need it to be a `public`